# Append json metadata with data

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

i want to append below json with the data

```
meta = [{
        "output_metadata": {
            "api_URL": apiURL,
            "query_execution_time": queryExecTime,
            "api_execution_time": apiExecTime,    
        }
    }]

jsondata = json.dumps([dict(ix) for ix in Data], default=str)
```

json data:

```
{"data": [{"id": "1234", "name": "jhon", "dept": "APA"}]}

meta.append(jsondata)
```

expected result:

```
{"output_metadata": {"api_url": "xxxxx", "query_execution_time":"xxxxx", "api_execution_time":"xxxxx"}},{"data": "[{"id": "1234", "name": "jhon", "dept": "APA"}]}
```

output:

```
{"output_metadata": {"api_url": "XXXXXX", "query_execution_time": "XXXXXX", "api_execution_time":"XXXXXX" }},{"data": "[{"\id": "1234\", "\name": "\jhon", "\dept": "\APA"}]}
```

How to remove \ from the final output?

Comment: Your expected result is invalid.

Comment: i am just trying to append two json but in output i am getting \

Answer (score 1):

If this thing you wrote above is python the meta variable you create is invalid because before every " you should use an escape character and every time you go in a new line. For example you should write:

```
        meta = ["{\
                \"output_metadata\": {\
                    \"api_URL\": apiURL,\
                    \"query_execution_time\": queryExecTime,\
                    \"api_execution_time\": apiExecTime,    \
                }\
            }"]    

        data = ["{\"data\": {\"id\": \"1234\", \"name\": \"jhon\", \"dept\": \"APA\"}]}"]

        meta.append(data)
```

Where you handle the json's as strings and then append them in one list. Is this what you want?

EDIT:  if you run something like

```
        data = [{"id": 1234, "name": "jhon", "dept": "APA" }]
        jdata= json.dumps([dict(ix) for ix in data], default=str) 
        apiURL = 'url'
        queryExecTime = 1 
        apiExecTime = 1 
        meta = [{ "output_metadata": { "api_url": apiURL, 
        "query_execution_time": queryExecTime,
        "api_execution_time": apiExecTime, } }]

        jdata = { "data": jdata } 

        meta.append(jdata)
        res = json.dumps(meta) 
        print(res)
```

the result will be:

```
         '[{"output_metadata": {"api_url": "url", "query_execution_time": 1, "api_execution_time": 1}}, {"data": "[{\\"id\\": 1234, \\"name\\": \\"jhon\\", \\"dept\\": \\"APA\\"}]"}]'
```

The \ are used as escape characters for the ". You see the result as a literal string.

Comment: data = json.dumps([dict(ix) for ix in Data], default=str)

Comment: how to remove this escape character?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean? which variable is Data? paste your code here

Comment: jdata= json.dumps([dict(ix) for ix in qData], default=str)


    apiURL = request.url
    queryExecTime = qedata
    apiExecTime = time.time() - api_start_time

    meta = [{
        "output_metadata": {
            "api_url": apiURL,
            "query_execution_time": queryExecTime,
            "api_execution_time": apiExecTime,
            

        }
    }]
    jdata = {
        "data": jdata

    }
    
    meta.append(jdata)
    
    return json.dumps(meta)